# driving WS2812 led strip without PCM GPIO

Tags: gpio, ws2812

I'm using a Rpi 3b+ and a Pisound Hat which use all pins excluded :
GND, 5V, BCM7 (CE1), 3v3, BCM5, BCM6, BCM22, BCM23, BCM27, BCM4 (GPLCKL0), BCM15 (RXD), BCM14 (TXD), BCM2 (SDA).

i want to drive a stripe of WS2812 but it looks like i can't because it needs a GPIO pin as the 18? (so strictly with PCM)
is it possible or i'm mistaking?
if yes, any turnaround?
cheers

Comment: `looks like i can't` ... what does this mean? .... you tried, and failed? ... you thought that you might fail, so you did not even try?

Comment: hi! of course i tried all of the free GPIOs. When i run it without hat on pin 18, it works, otherwise if i use one of those GPIOs left unused from the pisound hat, i receive the answer:
''gpio is illegal for led channel''.
i was wondering if i just did something wrong or if is really not possible to do or if eventually there is a way to drive the led from one of those ports

Comment: did you fix it ?

Comment: not yet. i tried digital pwm emulation rpio.pwm library but i couldn't make it. looking for a different kins of led strip now.